# NSFetchedResultsController indexPathForObject not counting sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am updating a download view/button on a cell, and when I go to update my cell, I am not getting the correct section.

My code to get the index and update the download progress is this:

```
Object *obj = (Object *)notification.object;
NSIndexPath *index = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:obj];
MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
DownloadProgressButtonView *buttonView = (DownloadProgressButtonView *)cell.accessoryView;
NSNumber *progressLong = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"progress"];
float progress = [progressLong floatValue];
NSNumber *totalBytesLong = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"totalBytes"];
float totalBytes = [totalBytesLong floatValue];
buttonView.progress = progress *.01;
float totalDownloadEstimate = totalBytes / 1.0e6;
float megaBytesDownloaded = (progress *.01) * totalDownloadEstimate;
cell.bottomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f MB of %.1f MB", megaBytesDownloaded, totalDownloadEstimate];
```

If I have two objects, each in a different section, they have the same row (0). When I go to update my cell, it updates the cell in section 1 instead of section 0. How do I fix this?

I can put whatever other code is needed. It works perfectly if I just disable sections in my NSFetchedResultsController.

My NSFetchedResultsController and delegates.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *nameString = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:self.sectionSortDescriptor ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:self.sortDescriptor ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameString,descriptor, nil]];
    NSString *downloadStartedString = @"Preparing to download";
    NSString *downloadingString = @"Downloading";
    NSString *downloadPausedString = @"Download paused";
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(downloaded == YES) OR (downloadStatus like[cd] %@) OR (downloadStatus like[cd] %@) OR (downloadStatus like[cd]%@)",downloadPausedString, downloadStartedString,downloadingString];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    _fetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:self.sectionNameString
                                                   cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

/*
 NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods to respond to additions, removals and so on.
 */
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    switch(type)
    {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:(StudioTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            NSLog(@"A table item was moved");
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            NSLog(@"A table item was updated");
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Finally when the download status changes, I update the object and send a notification to update the cell with the new status:

```
- (void)updateCell:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    Object *obj = (Object *)notification.object;
    NSIndexPath *index = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:obj];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: How do you update the cell? You usually don't have to call `cellForRow...` to do that.

Comment: This is just to get the cell that matches the Object that I am receiving a notification from. I don't refresh the cell, just a view in the cell.

Comment: Please can you post that 1) the code that initialises the FRC, 2) the table view datasource methods, and 3) the FRC delegate methods?

Comment: Updated the question with all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating cells this way is not reliable. A cell updated in such a way will sooner or later be reused. The cell's subviews will be re-configured by `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, based on the data provided by the datasource.

You should make changes to the `Object` itself (instead of passing them in notification's `userInfo`) and save the managed object context. Then `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` callbacks will fire, allowing you to reload the corresponding row. Then you should set all the properties of `MyTableViewCell` in `configureCell:atIndexPath`.

And the `configureCell:` method should be called from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, not from the fetched results controller delegate method. The general pattern is to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` in `controllerDidChangeObject:`. Otherwise you can run into some cell reuse issues.

An idea on how the code should look like:

```
- (void)updateCell:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //depending on your Core Data contexts setup,
    // you may need embed the code below in performBlock: on object's context,
    // I omitted it for clarity
    Object *obj = (Object *)notification.object;
    //save changes to the object, for example:
    NSNumber *progressLong = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"progress"];
    obj.progress = progressLong; 
    //set all the properties you will need in configureCell:, then save context
    [obj.magagedObjectContext save:&someError];
}
```

then the fetched results controller will call `controllerDidChangeObject:`, in this method you should reload the row:

```
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        break;
```

finally, configure the cell (let's assume that you call `configureCell:atIndexPath` from  `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`):

```
- (void)configureCell:(MyTableViewCell*)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    Object *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    DownloadProgressButtonView *buttonView = (DownloadProgressButtonView*) cell.accessoryView;
    buttonView.progress = object.progress.floatValue *.01;
    //and so on
}
```